# Focussing the same row in two listViews when pressed

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'd like to focus on the same row in two different listViews when either one of the listViews is pressed/focused. An example below

Example
[Correct Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6JxaY.png)

This is what presently happens

Example
[Present Display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3KReS.png)

```
//Initialize Left and Right ListViews
ListView<String> listViewLeft = new ListView<String>();
ListView<String> listViewRight = new ListView<String>();

//Set focus properties here
```

Any tips would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener((Change<? extends Integer> c) -> {
    listViewRight.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    for (int selected : listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()) {
        listViewRight.select(selected);
    }
});
listViewRight.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener((Change<? extends Integer> c) -> {
    listViewLeft.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
    for (int selected : listViewRight.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices()) {
        listViewLeft.select(selected);
    }
});
```

But maybe you really want a `TableView` with two columns, instead of two list views?